# Publish. NET core Web App. In window and linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I developed a mvc web application in .net core with vs 2017 for windows. I published on iss through the publication procedure and all work fine. If I take the product assembly and put it under linux apache does not work. why do you have to fill in specifically for linux? All runtime are running... other .net core linux web app works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this guide on hosting ASP.NET Core with Apache. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache

Comment: thanks it works, I do not understand why visual studio does not have an ide for publishing on Linux but you have to do it from the comsole. it would be sufficient to use a target operating system.